# Grails - Controller chain and model disapearance

Tags: grails, parameters, model, controller, chain

I am trying to use the `chain` feature to call an other method and render a merged model.
This is how I call the `chain`:

**Controller: emailToNotify, Method: sendEmailConfirmation**

```
if (someCommandObject.hasErrors())
                chain(controller: "creditProvider", action: "rank", model: [emailToNotify: epnc, somethingToDisplay: "Boom !!!!"])
```

This is how my `rank` method end-up in my `creditProvider` controller:

**Controller: creditProvider, action: rank**

```
render (view: 'simulateResult', model: [bim : bam, boom : bimbamboom])
```

I do not manage to call `${emailToNotify}` or `${somethingToDisplay}` from my `simulateResult.gsp` view.

I have already used `chain` before in this exact same way, and it was (and still is) working properly.

**Any idea why the model is not passed properly to the view ?**

Any help most welcome as always.
All the best,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`chain` only works if the final action returns a `Map` and not if the final action uses the `render` call.  To get what you are doing to work you'll have to manually merge the implicit variable `chainModel` with the model you're passing back in to the `render`.

Comment: Thank you, you have ended-up 2hours of tracing variables :) 
Is this written somewhere in the documentation ?? 
I did not read this there, but maybe I missed it.

Comment: I don't know of any specific documentation on that rule.  I don't remember where I first learned it either.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with this and found that one way to get around this is to use the Spring ModelAndView object.  From the firstController:

```
chain(controller: second, action: 'chainedMethod', model: [modelField2: '2'])
```

Then in the secondController:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
...
def chainedMethod() {
  return new ModelAndView('/other/view', [modelField1: '1'])
}
```

This works for me using Grails 2.1.1 so can't speak to how well it works with other versions.  Hope that helps other people, had to dig around and try a few different routes before getting this.